# Gtk.Bin derived class does not receive MotionNotifyEvent

Tags: gtk, gtk#

i am developing a Gtk# based application which uses a custom widget derived from Gtk.Bin. For some reason not known to me, it does not receive mouse movement events. The code below is never called:

```
    [GLib.ConnectBefore]
    protected override bool OnMotionNotifyEvent (Gdk.EventMotion evnt)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine( "Mouse move!" );

        return base.OnMotionNotifyEvent (evnt);                 
    }
```

I have also extended the Event mask of the widget to receive all events (in the constructor):

```
AddEvents(( int ) Gdk.EventMask.AllEventsMask );
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gtk.Bin is a windowless container so it does not receive mouse events by default.

You can create a Gdk.Window manually in your subclass in order to receive mouse events, or the easier path is to subclass Gtk.EventBox, which is a Gtk.Bin subclass designed for this purpose by internally creating its own Gdk window.